# Generate Selenium Cucumber reports without overwriting the previous Maven test output result?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, cucumber

I need to save each report files separately in Report directory on each Run.How can we create Report files by concatenating current date & Time along with the file name .
I have used the below code in my TestRunnerTest.java to generate Extentreport in cucumber-selenium framework.

```
package testRunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

    features = "src/test/resources"
            , glue= {"stepDefinition"}
    , plugin = { "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}, 
            monochrome = true
    )
public class TestRunnerTest {
public static WebDriver driver;
private static TestRunnerTest sharedInstance = new TestRunnerTest();

 private TestRunnerTest() { }

 public static TestRunnerTest getInstance() {
        return sharedInstance;
    }

 @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {   

           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"E:\\ChromeDriverNew\\chromedriver.exe");
           driver=new ChromeDriver();

           driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
    }
 @AfterClass
    public static void after() {

     Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));  
     driver.quit();
    }
}
```

And this is my POM dependency file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>selcuc</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoEurasia</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>   
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.12.2</version> 
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
   <build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>          
            </configuration>
          </plugin>  
          <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
    </plugin>                                        
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can anyone answer how to generate Report logs on each execution using Selenium- Cucumber Maven Framework. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own cucumber `Plugin` that decorates the `ExtentCucumberFormatter` and initializes it with a different file name. Have a look at the existing plugins for hints on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But can you please answer me how to Save the Report files of each execution without overwriting to the previous report file.

Comment: By creating a plugin that writes to a different file each time.

Comment: Actually I am just a beginner and  i have the basic knowledge in this framework. so could you please help me to solve this .

Comment: Then you can't solve this problem. You may have to find a more experienced coworker to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have got the solution , but below there are 2 ways you can do it.

1 . Set the value of plugin in the tetsRunner.java file upto ExtentCucumberFormatter i.e ,plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"} and execute the tetscase . Here by default the report will be created under the Output folder in your project directory (Just refresh your project from the Project Explorer , output folder would be generated)

2. Set the dynamic output file path like below in the @BeforeClass Hooker as below  in the testRunner file.

   ```
   @CucumberOptions(
   features = "src/test/java/Features"
   ,glue= {"StepDefinations"}
   ,plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"}
   ,monochrome = true
   )
   public class testRunner {
   @BeforeClass
   public static void setup() {
   ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
   String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
   String userDir =System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
   extentProperties.setReportPath(userDir+ 
                                "/target/cucumberreports/report_"+timeStamp+".html");
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your POM (Plugin part) you can do something like this:

```
    <configuration>
         <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
         <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-report/cluecumber_report_${maven.build.timestamp}</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
</configuration>
```

With the Maven.build.timestamp will be generated folders with date stamps (UTM 00:00)